# Pytorch tensor.method() vs torch.method(tensor)?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, deep-learning, pytorch, instance

I've noticed that you can often invoke a method working with tensors from the torch module itself, or call it as a bound method on an instance of a torch tensor.

For instance:

```
import torch
my_tens = torch.ones((3,2)) 
another_tens = torch.ones((3,2))
res_tens = my_tens==another_tens

# both are equivalent:
torch.all(res_tens, dim=1)
res_tens.all(dim=1)
```

Similarly, `.sum()` and other methods work the same way. Why is that? Are there any advantages to using one approach or the other?

Answer (score 0):

These two options are equivalent and runs the same implementation "under the hood".
You can use whatever is more convenient for you and makes your code more readable.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a source for that? Why did they structure it that way?